# Is it fine to play PS4 pro games on a full hd monitor?

Tags: ps4, hardware, monitor

Will there be a lot of loss in video quality if one uses a Full HD (1920x1080) monitor to play PS4 Pro?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: the image doesn't upscale magically to improve its quality, no. The resolution will remain the same, it will just be enlarged. But is that really what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all! In fact, you might find yourself having a delightful experience considering your monitor probably has a munch better refresh rate (Hz) than your normal television.